# How to estimate maximum n given complexity and amount of time?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

Say you've implemented a program that completes it's work with O(2<sup>n</sup>) time complexity, and you measure the actual running time of the program as:

- n<sub>1</sub>: 0.006s
- n<sub>100,000</sub>: 16.057s

Since time will grow exponentially as n increases, what is the typical way to estimate the maximum n given a time t? For example, if time t is 1 minute or 1 hour, how do you "correctly" estimate n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  Mathematically, you can't conclude anything about the running time for all $n$, given just two points (given the running time at just two values of $n$).  There are many possible curves that might go through those two curves; two points aren't enough to determine a curve.  The running time might be something like

$$\frac{1}{2^{100}} 2^n + n^2.$$

Or, it might be something like

$$\frac{1}{2^{95}} 2^n + \frac{1}{10000} n.$$

Or, the running time might be

$$\frac{1}{100000000} n^2.$$

Or any number of other possibilities.

---

That said, in practice it seems very unlikely that you have an algorithm whose running time on all instances of size $n$ is $\Theta(2^n)$... and yet for $n=100,000$ it completes in 16 seconds.  That's a bit silly.  In practice, it *could* happen if the algorithm is sufficiently weird, but not bloody likely in practice.

Comment: "Mathematically, you can't conclude anything about the running time from just two running times." -- well, if we get a $\Theta$ (or something better) we can try and estimate the constants of the leading term. That won't necessarily get us close to the real running times in absolute terms, but relatively close for huge $n$. That said, here we only have an $O$ so we can't say anything.